# How to edit a .plt file with GNUplot

Tags: linux, plot, gnuplot

This is a very basic question but I am having trouble finding the answer. I'm trying to load a .plt file and then edit it and save the new plot as a postscript file. I have loaded the file using

```
load "filename.plt"
```

Which then opens the plot as it is. Then I'm trying to add a second curve on the same plot from the same .dat file as the original one. I tried simply doing

```
plot "filename.dat" using 1:3 title 'plot title'
replot
```

But this doesn't change the original plot at all. How do I edit a .plt file / how do I add a new curve (and fit) to it?

Comment: Open the *.plt file in a text editor of your choice to add whatever commands you like.

Answer (score 0):

In order to plot two curves in one diagram, you must use something like

```
plot "file.dat" using 1:2 title "curve 1", "file.dat" using 1:3 title "curve 2"
```

I suggest to edit the `plot` command in your "filename.plt" accordingly and then load it again with `load "filename.plt"`.

Answer (score 0):

As an answer along the lines of the interactive method you tried, try the following commands.

```
gnuplot> load 'filename.plt'
gnuplot> replot "filename.dat" using 1:3 title 'plot title'
```

By using `replot` command, you can add a new plot to the previous plots.